HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core App Failed to Start with IIS But Working Fine By Using Command dotnetun
I know some people might flag this question as a duplicate, but my issue is different. Recently, I received an application based on version 6.0.33. I installed the Hosting Bundle on my server with the same version, and I checked by running the website using the dotnet run command, which opened fine. However, whenever I try to open it in IIS, I get the error: 'HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core App Failed to Start with IIS.'
I've spent a lot of time searching online, including reading this Stack Overflow thread: HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start, but none of the solutions worked for me. Then, I found this article: https://www.quickpickdeal.com/coding/http-error-500-30-asp-net-core-app-failed-to-start-with-iis-a-real-world-solut. The article mentioned that I should try installing all three components: the Hosting Bundle, .NET SDK, and Runtime. After trying this, it worked, but I’m still not sure why all three are needed. Shouldn’t it work with just the Hosting Bundle?


You can first rule out common issues, https://docs.lextudio.com/jexusmanager/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics 2) Revise your code to log/handle unhandled exceptions properly. 3) When all other options failed, build ASP.NET Core module from source code and debug into it.


For this issue, we need enable the stdlogs to see what happened, without the logs, we don't know what has happened. I guess there may be something wrong with the hosting module inside the issue.
